# java card authenticated with JC-Manager , but received 6985 in GPJ Authentication

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I have a javacard, this is outputs when I want to authenticate the card via **GPJ** and **JC-Manager** :

**GPJ Tool Output :**

```
C:\Users\ghasemi\Desktop\gpj-20120310>java -jar gpj.jar
Found terminals: [PC/SC terminal ACS CCID USB Reader 0]
Found card in terminal: ACS CCID USB Reader 0
ATR: 3B 68 00 00 00 73 C8 40 12 00 90 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
DEBUG: Response APDU: 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00
Successfully selected Security Domain OP201a A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 80 50 00 00 08 C8 12 42 39 22 8D 5E 24
DEBUG: Response APDU: 00 00 11 60 01 00 7F 8B 0A F9 02 02 02 24 AB 7A 47 C8 17 DD 03 75 44 3F 76 8E 12 BE 90 00

DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 10 B6 09 4F FF C0 0D D2 CC B0 CE B1 3E 20 57 30 D4
DEBUG: Response APDU: 69 85
DEBUG: Command  APDU: 84 82 00 00 08 B6 09 4F FF C0 0D D2 CC
DEBUG: Response APDU: 69 85

javax.smartcardio.CardException: External authenticate failed. SW: 69 85
        at net.sourceforge.gpj.cardservices.GlobalPlatformService.openSecureChannel(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.gpj.cardservices.GlobalPlatformService.main(Unknown Source)
```

**JC-Manager Output :**

**Note: Keys set to** `404142434445464748494A4B4C4D4E4F`

```
Selecting Card Manager
***********************
-> 00 A4 04 00 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
<- 6F 10 84 08 A0 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 A5 04 9F 65 01 FF 90 00
************
Init Update
*************
-> 80 50 00 00 08 B6 42 6E BB DC 0E DF E8
<- 00 00 11 60 01 00 7F 8B 0A F9 02 02 02 23 7E 5D E1 67 E0 0A 3D 67 91 7E B8 D6 14 59 90 00

HostChallenge: B6 42 6E BB DC 0E DF E8
CardChallenge: 7E 5D E1 67 E0 0A
Card Calculated Card Cryptogram: 3D 67 91 7E B8 D6 14 59
Derivation Data is 01 82 02 23 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Host Cryptogram Data (to encrypt) 02 23 7E 5D E1 67 E0 0A B6 42 6E BB DC 0E DF E8 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
Card Cryptogram Data (to encrypt for verification) B6 42 6E BB DC 0E DF E8 02 23 7E 5D E1 67 E0 0A 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
S_ENC: 9F 46 0D 11 18 88 F2 E2 1C D2 4A F5 00 D0 51 7D 9F 46 0D 11 18 88 F2 E2
The Current session MAC key is 99 96 8E ED 46 99 59 DE 20 B1 F8 36 0E 0C 7F DE
The Current session DEK key is 98 4D 50 CA 56 5A F3 4E 84 0E CF 12 3B E0 1D C3
Encrypted CardCryptoGram is 8E 07 30 FB E7 13 23 F4 CD D9 13 12 29 F3 7C 16 3D 67 91 7E B8 D6 14 59
Encrypted HostCryptoGram is 41 34 E9 1E C7 41 0D 62 EC D3 E1 2A 6A D1 7D 13 A9 CD 65 16 AE 5B 99 59

-> 84 82 03 00 10 A9 CD 65 16 AE 5B 99 59 1D 88 41 EF 90 09 03 32
<- 90 00
Authenticated
```

As you see, a same card, has two output via **External AUTHENTICATION**.successfully authenticate with **JC-Manager** , but received `6985` [**Conditions of use not satisfied**] in **GPJ**.
Why?

Comment: EXTERNAL AUTH request depends on card challenge received in INIT UPDATE command and that's why you see different EXT AUTH requests. Are you sure you're using correct keys with gpj?

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid : My problem is Status Words difference! not APDU Command's data fields difference :).And, Yes I'm sure. **GPJ** tool use `404142...4F` as key by default.

Comment: In the process of establishing secure channel, the 6985 status word usually means the keys are wrong.

Comment: @MohammadBanisaeid : in the case of wrong password, we receive `6982` that mean **Security status not satisfied**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`P1` in the `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` APDU command accept `00` or `01` or `03` values.

`03 --->  C-DECRYPTION and C-MAC`

`01 --->  C-MAC`

`00 --->  No secure messaging expected`

as you see in the codes that you put in the question, **JC-Manager** send External Authenticate with `P1=03` , but **GPJ** send External Authenticate command with `P1=00`

I think your card is in SECURED state. and in `SECUTED` state the only way to authentate is using *C-DECRYPTION* and *C-MAC*. [I don't know why!] so, GPJ use `P1=00` in authentication and it fails.